# Htaccess redirect all .html pages to php get variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My urls are currently like:

/events.html
/contact.html

What I want to do is, redirect them to a php get variable.

E.g events.html = index.php?page=events

Any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

Thanks A lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) here.

With the rule something along the lines of (assuming mod_rewrite is installed and enabled and you're putting it in a .htaccess file)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*).html /index.php?page=$1
```